# Create two matrices from one dataset in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I’m new in R so my question is probably trivial. I would like to make a matrix `x1i` of 50 random vectors (from matrix `x`) with condition [,27]==0. For example: in my `x` matrix I have 70 vectors where [,27]==0 and I would like to randomly select 50 of them.

```
x<-matrixData #100 rows and 27 columns

xi<-x[x[,27]==0,]

x1i<-xi[sample(1:50),]
```

Is that ok? Now I would just like to create another matrix `x2` from the remaining (50) vectors/rows that were not in `x1i`.
So simply x minus x1i.
Everything I try, I get

> Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
sample<-sample(which(x[,27]==0),50)

x[sample,] #50 rows sample
x[-sample,] #other rows
```

Starting from your `x` matrix a sample (variable `sample`) composed by 50 rows based on the condition `which(x[,27]==0)` is extracted. Using `-sample` you are able to extract the rest of the matrix.